# Perl adjust xsltMaxDepth (--maxdepth) error

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I have simple perl program that reads in an xml file and xslt file and run the transforms against it like this

COMMAND:

```
perl perl_xslt_translator.pl C000143.xml 04_TestStylesheet.xsl C000143_04.xml PROG123
```

The perl code looks like this.

CODE:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::Simple;
use XML::LibXSLT;
use XML::LibXML;
use Data::Dumper;

print "Perl Starting ... \n\n"; 

#
# This reads the filename as an argument
#
# store the 1st argument into the variable
my ($XML_FILE, $XSLT_FILE, $OUTPUT_FILE, $PROGRAM_NAME) = @ARGV;

print "XML File: $XML_FILE ... \n";
print "XSLT File: $XSLT_FILE ... \n";
print "PRGM Name: $PROGRAM_NAME ... \n";
print "Output File: $OUTPUT_FILE ... \n";

#create output file
open(my $output_xml_file_name, '>', $OUTPUT_FILE);

my %in_params = (
  PROGRAM      => "$PROGRAM_NAME",
);


my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();

print "Reading files ... \n\n";
my $source_xml = $parser->parse_file($XML_FILE);
my $xslt_doc = $parser->parse_file($XSLT_FILE);

my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($xslt_doc);

print "Transforming XML ... \n\n";
my $results = $stylesheet->transform($source_xml, XML::LibXSLT::xpath_to_string(%in_params));


print "Saving XML ... \n\n";
print $output_xml_file_name "$results";

print "\nPerl End ... \n\n";
```

The problem I have is that for very large XML files that are 500MB I get the following error. With smaller files of 70 - 100MB it works fine. How can I adjust the maxdepth from 250 to lets say 5000?

OUPUT ERROR:

```
runtime error: file 04_TestStylesheet.xsl element param
xsltApplyXSLTTemplate: A potential infinite template recursion was detected.
You can adjust xsltMaxDepth (--maxdepth) in order to raise the maximum number of nested template cal
ls and variables/params (currently set to 250).
```

Per one of the user's suggestion below I changed this line to

```
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new()->max_depth(1000);
```

but now I get this error.

```
Can't locate object method "parse_stylesheet" via package "250" (perhaps you forgot to load "250"?)
at perl_xslt_translator.pl line 38.

Here line38# my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($xslt_doc);
```

Comment: It's literally the first thing mentioned in the docs for XML::LibXSLT

Comment: @ikegami I tried this "XML::LibXSLT->max_depth(1000);" and this is what is thrown to me in my perl run "syntax error at perl_xslt_translator.pl line 6, near "use XML::LibXSLT->max_depth"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at perl_xslt_translator.pl line 7."

Comment: No, you didn't do `XML::LibXSLT->max_depth(1000);`. According to the error message, there was a `use` in there.

Comment: @ikegami please see my updated question above. I added your suggestion and get another error.

Comment: Seriously! You're still not using `XML::LibXSLT->max_depth(1000);`.

Comment: Besides the configuration to allow more space for execution stack, thus more posible recursion, the transformation itself **(not shown)** is missing some important code design as [D&C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs, simply add the following to your program:

```
XML::LibXSLT->max_depth(1000);
```

Do not change `use XML::LibXSLT;`

Do not change `my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();`